# Controlling psql decimal digits in output

Tags: postgresql, psql

I would like to know if there exist a parameter or global variabile to have float (or double) values in PostgreSQL printed with maximum N-digits when results are presented in the psql shell.

I know about to_char, I am looking for a global behaviour in psql.

bye

Answer (score 0):

up to some point you can control number of decimals defining the length of numeric, eg:

```
t=# select (2/3.0)::numeric(3,3)::float;
 float8
--------
  0.667
(1 row)

Time: 89.094 ms
t=# select (2/3.0)::numeric(9,9)::float;
   float8
-------------
 0.666666667
(1 row)
```

Comment: Your solution is better than `to_char` which I was using because, at least, it keeps the type numeric. On the other side it is not global, unfortunately.

Comment: Note that this may fail if the number won't fit in the left side. i.e. 423.234::numeric(4,2) will fail.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe yes. if you use numeric to control length, you need to maintain the whole length as well

Comment: Yeah it's easy to just over do it to be safe. Numeric(200,190) etc for 10 to the right and no chance to overflow for any typical number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature or, in generlal, much data format control in psql.